# php - using sprintf to add "+" sign removes decimals from formatted number

Tags: php, printf, currency, number-formatting

I want to do this to show changes in a stock index:

```
12 => +12.00
150.5 => +150.50
-30.2 => -30.20
-2.85193 => -2.85
```

I've got this:

`sprintf("%+d", number_format(floatval($key), 2, '.', ','))`

But it's stripping the decimals from the formatted number and returning things like `+45`.

Is there an efficient way to get both a + sign and decimals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%d` is for integers, you have to use `%f` for floating point.

```
sprintf("%+.2f", $key);
```

Unfortunately, you can't get commas with this. They also wouldn't have worked with your original code, because `%d` parses the argument as an integer, and it would stop reading the number when it gets to the comma.

If you need both the sign and commas, you can do:

```
($key >= 0 ? '+' : '') . number_format(floatval($key), 2, '.', ','))
```

Comment: I think you would still have to pass through number_format to get the thousands separator in though.

Comment: @sebu are you sure you aren't doing `%+.6f`?

Comment: @Orangepill I was forgetting the `.2`, hehe.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the great solution for the sign and commas, very nice.